Not showing any content after splash screen in testflight ios app
I am creating expo app which is working fine on expo go on both ios and android. I am getting no error while running the app but when I submit app on app store testflight and test through it, it is showing no content just a blank screen after splash. I runs both cmd npx expo start and npx expo start --no-dev --minify in boht case app is working correctly.
Anyone can you please solve this issue
my app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Pixie",
    "slug": "Pixie",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.shahzadsiddique.Pixie"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.shahzadsiddique.Pixie"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-font"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "90241c2e-a05b-4014-9162-0a482e9313e8"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/90241c2e-a05b-4014-9162-0a482e9313e8"
    },
    "newArchEnabled": true
  }
}


package.json
{
  "name": "pixie",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.46.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.59.19",
    "expo": "^52.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.2",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~52.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}



using patch package will solve the issue, in my case I just add
"postinstall": "patch-package" in package.json script object. and and then run npm i patch-package
After the install finish I create the build and upload it to testflight and it works.
